# Right way to manage HTTP connection in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

I have written two programs which handle the HTTP request. I wanted to know if one is better than other -

Program 1 (Using HttpURLConnection)

```
          URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");

          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

          connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

          connection.setDoOutput(false);

          connection.connect();

          reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

          stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

Program 2 (Using HttpPost)

```
         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://test.com");

         HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

         InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

         InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
```

Also in program 2, I use a singleton to get the connection object. But in program 1 there is no global connection object and I need to recreate the HttpURLConnection object everytime I make a request. Please let me know if I am on the right track.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library. 
Then you can avoid these basic stuffs. The one things I like most is HTTP requests happen outside the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Also in program 2, I use a singleton to get the connection object. But in program 1 there is no global connection object and I need to recreate the HttpURLConnection object everytime I make a request.

**Method 2 looks like simpler, but it's so old** :

> **Apache HTTP Client** - HTTPPost
>
> DefaultHttpClient and its sibling AndroidHttpClient are extensible
>   HTTP clients suitable for web browsers. They have large and flexible
>   APIs. Their implementation is stable and they have few bugs. But the
>   large size of this API makes it difficult for us to improve it without
>   breaking compatibility. The Android team is not actively working on
>   Apache HTTP Client.
>
> **HttpURLConnection**
>
> HttpURLConnection is a general-purpose, lightweight HTTP client
>   suitable for most applications. This class has humble beginnings, but
>   its focused API has made it easy for us to improve steadily.
>
> Prior to Froyo, HttpURLConnection had some frustrating bugs.

We should **choose method 1 when** :

> For Gingerbread and better, HttpURLConnection is the best choice. Its
>   simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent
>   compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and
>   save battery. New applications should use HttpURLConnection; it is
>   where we will be spending our energy going forward.

And **method 2 when** :

> Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.

Thanks,